# Magento parser error "Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found"

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, xml

I am getting these errors in system.log.

```
2017-06-20T11:59:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in home/www/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 512
2017-06-20T11:59:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():   in /home/www/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 512
2017-06-20T11:59:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /home/www/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 512
```

I tried debugging them by adjusting the loadstring function in the config.php file:

```
public function loadString($string)
{
if (is_string($string)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);
    if(!$xml){
        Mage::log('XML_ERROR: ' . $string);
    }
    if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
        $this->_xml = $xml;
        return true;
    }
} else {
    Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
}
return false;
}
```

The response in the system.log is not pointing to any logic location or file. How to debug this:

```
2017-06-20T11:59:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: ’°#  .   ½; ô..                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2017-06-20T11:59:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
```

Changed the error login as sugested in the comments. This is what the response is now:

```
2017-06-20T12:43:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: classblock  in /home/www/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Block/Navigation.php on line 186
2017-06-20T12:43:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: nothumbnail  in /home/www/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Block/Navigation.php on line 84
2017-06-20T12:43:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: classblock  in /home/www/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Block/Navigation.php on line 186
2017-06-20T12:43:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): LibXMLError Object
(
[level] => 3
[code] => 4
[column] => 1
[message] => Start tag expected, '<' not found

[file] => 
[line] => 1
)

2017-06-20T12:43:53+00:00 DEBUG (7): LibXMLError Object
(
[level] => 3
[code] => 4
[column] => 1
[message] => Start tag expected, '<' not found

[file] => 
[line] => 1
)
```

Got this error:

```
2017-06-20T14:19:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): LibXMLError Object
(
[level] => 3
[code] => 4
[column] => 1
[message] => Start tag expected, '<' not found

[file] => ./app/design/frontend/default/theme313k/layout/cmsmart
[line] => 1
)
```

This is the corresponding file contents. I don't see anything wrong with that file. Also tried to remove whitespaces etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="top.menu" >
          <action  method="unsetChild" ><name>catalog.topnav</name>     </action>
          <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav2" template="page/html/topmenu_2.phtml"/>
           <block type="megamenu/navigation"  name="catalog.topnav.megamenu">
              <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
              <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
           </block>
    </reference>

</default>
</layout>
```

Comment: If you try opening each XML file your extension requests (and it's configuration) in notepad, or less,  do you have any weird characters at the beginning of the file? Might be an encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**, we traced down the XML error back to some issues with the server. The server was being hit by a large scale brute force atack. Somehow XML errors with some strange special characters are generated when the server can not handle the load (seems like Apache had problems closing all child processes).

**Steps** to diagnose and solve the problem

- Stopped all external traffic by blocking every IP address except our own with .htaccess. After a couple off minutes the site worked as expected, no more error where generated.
- Installed Free Watchlog extension and register all login attempts. We noticed 120K attempts the last couple off days.
- Blocked all IP adresses that attempted to log in. We used an third  party extension.
- Don't forget to allow external traffic via the .htaccess file again.

Answer (score 5):

Please check your `config.xml`, `system.xml` and all the `layout.xml` files.

For debugging you can try this ... create file in magento root

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// adjust template path
$dir = "./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/*";

foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        Mage::log($error);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Output looks like

```
2017-06-20T13:28:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => ./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
    [1] => LibXMLError Object
        (
            [level] => 3
            [code] => 76
            [column] => 28
            [message] => Opening and ending tag mismatch: reference line 191 and catalog_product_view

            [file] => ./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
            [line] => 262
        )

)
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php

---

**Edit:** check all XML files ...

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$root = './app';
$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
);

foreach ($iterator as $path => $item) {
    if ($item->isFile() && $item->getExtension() == 'xml') {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
        foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            Mage::log($error);
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the output from system.log to the question. Shouldn't this be pointing to an XML files?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Let me check this: 
1.) Create a file with the code above and upload it to Magento root, change template path?
2.) Run file in browser
3.) Check errors in system.log?

Comment: Yep ... set `$dir` to the template you use.

Comment: Note this is only for layout XMLs, but error can also come from `etc/config.xml` ...  so this could be changed a little bit. Pls let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: I got this as feedback, only nothing seems wrong with that file: 

(
    [level] => 3
    [code] => 4
    [column] => 1
    [message] => Start tag expected, '<' not found

    [file] => ./app/design/frontend/default/theme313k/layout/cmsmart
    [line] => 1
)

Comment: Check carefully ... maybe use: http://www.xmlvalidation.com

Comment: I tried using that. Also updated the original question with the code.

Comment: Save this file as UTF-8 w/o BOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60772/discussion-between-matthijshofstede-and-sv3n).

Comment: I fixed the issue. Thanks for the support. Still investigating what actually happened.

Comment: At this moment it looks like the problems are server related. Hosting provider is investigating at this moment. The site is going on and offline every few hours.

Comment: OK, but this is independent from the invalid XML-file.

Comment: Statusupdate: We noticed a heavy brute force atack when these problems started. Causing problems on the server (to many connections, also apache was not able to close all of the processes). I am not sure but somehow this generated the xml error. Blocking all traffic from external IP's actually made the error go away so I think it should be related to loads off traffic. We will be monitoring for a couple off days to see if this is the case.