# magento 1.9 simplexml_load_string error

Tags: magento-1.9

This is my System.log what is this problem? what should i do to fix this?

```
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 197: parser error : expected '&gt;'  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): congo-kinshasa-post&gt;&lt;ftd&gt;0&lt;/ftd&gt;&lt;cook-islands-post&gt;0&lt;/cook-islands-post&gt;&lt;2go&gt;0&lt;/  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 197: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: config line 1 and unparseable  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): congo-kinshasa-post&gt;&lt;ftd&gt;0&lt;/ftd&gt;&lt;cook-islands-post&gt;0&lt;/cook-islands-post&gt;&lt;2go&gt;0&lt;/  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 197: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): congo-kinshasa-post&gt;&lt;ftd&gt;0&lt;/ftd&gt;&lt;cook-islands-post&gt;0&lt;/cook-islands-post&gt;&lt;2go&gt;0&lt;/  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-24T16:44:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
```

I have used the script from @sv3n and detected a file with problems, now this file its ok.
But the error is still happening:

```
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ost&gt;0&lt;/congo-kinshasa-post&gt;&lt;ftd&gt;0&lt;/ftd&gt;&lt;cook-islands-post&gt;0&lt;/cook-islands-post&gt;&lt;  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 197: parser error : expected '&gt;'  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): congo-kinshasa-post&gt;&lt;ftd&gt;0&lt;/ftd&gt;&lt;cook-islands-post&gt;0&lt;/cook-islands-post&gt;&lt;2go&gt;0&lt;/  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 197: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: config line 1 and unparseable  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): congo-kinshasa-post&gt;&lt;ftd&gt;0&lt;/ftd&gt;&lt;cook-islands-post&gt;0&lt;/cook-islands-post&gt;&lt;2go&gt;0&lt;/  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 197: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): congo-kinshasa-post&gt;&lt;ftd&gt;0&lt;/ftd&gt;&lt;cook-islands-post&gt;0&lt;/cook-islands-post&gt;&lt;2go&gt;0&lt;/  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2017-10-25T10:48:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/main_folder/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
```

Comment: Flush (config/layout) cache after fixing XML.

Comment: I have already done it...

Comment: Has this worked for you?

Answer (score 4):

Seems one of your parsed XML files isn't valid - like mismatching open/close tags.

See: [Magento parser error "Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179905/magento-parser-error-start-tag-expected-lt-not-found/179909#179909)

---

Please check your `config.xml`, `system.xml` and all the `layout.xml` files.

For debugging you can try this ... create file in magento root

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// adjust template path
$dir = "./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/*";

foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        Mage::log($error);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Output looks like

```
2017-06-20T13:28:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => ./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
    [1] => LibXMLError Object
        (
            [level] => 3
            [code] => 76
            [column] => 28
            [message] => Opening and ending tag mismatch: reference line 191 and catalog_product_view

            [file] => ./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
            [line] => 262
        )

)
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php

---

**Edit:** check all XML files ...

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$root = './app';
$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
);

foreach ($iterator as $path => $item) {
    if ($item->isFile() && $item->getExtension() == 'xml') {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
        foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            Mage::log($error);
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }
}
```