# Magento 1.9.x after refresh cache, site not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

After refresh cache on admin page, site not working.
Just show this message.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/jaspertra...', 510, Array)
#1 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ans...', 'Varien_Simplexm...')
#2 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(498): Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadString('{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ans...', 'Varien_Simplexm...')
#3 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Config.php(62): Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadFile('/home/jaspertra...')
#4 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1357): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Config->__construct(Array)
#5 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/design_con...', Array)
#6 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::getModel('core/design_con...', Array)
#7 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(105): Mage::getSingleton('core/design_con...')
#8 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1357): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->__construct(Array)
#9 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/design_pac...', Array)
#10 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::getModel('core/design_pac...', Array)
#11 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(155): Mage::getSingleton('core/design_pac...')
#12 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(124): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_initDesign()
#13 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(92): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_loadPart('design')
#14 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(789): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->load()
#15 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(512): Mage_Core_Model_App->loadArea('frontend')
#16 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(69): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#17 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#18 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#19 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home/jaspertradingllc/public_html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

Please help me .

Comment: You have some error in some xml file, check the `xml` that you changed recently

Comment: I never changed xml source file. Just refresh cache on the admin page.

Comment: Hi. I think it must be xml layout error where you have missing "<" starting tag in one of the xml file.  Have you tried with enable base theme? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten some space before starting the xml starting tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Check the system log for more details .

To do some debug where the error is comming, create a test.php file in the root and add this :

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$root = './app';
$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
);

foreach ($iterator as $path => $item) {
    if ($item->isFile() && $item->getExtension() == 'xml') {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
        foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            Mage::log($error);
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }

    }
```

Check the output and fix the errors . 
See this link for more info [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179905/magento-parser-error-start-tag-expected-lt-not-found)
(If that doesnt work for you than see the option of the ip restriction .)

Comment: few days ago have same problem after refresh cache. I just clear manually cache.  Then It was working. But today it is not working(already clear cache).

Comment: open index.php and see if you have spaces in top of the file , remove the spaces and check

Comment: I checked index.php file. No have space on the top.

Comment: Updated my answer , please check

Comment: Thank you your help. I will try to create test.php.

Comment: I created test.php file in root. But nothing happen. I load a page https://jaspertradingllc.com/test.php. Is this correct?

Comment: Check the logs @blackship76