# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 7: parser error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-upgrade, varien, system.log, simplexml

Just upgraded from 1.9.3 to 1.9.4, and now this is filling up `system.log`

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 7: parser error : XML
>   declaration allowed only at the start of the document in
>   /lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

Any advice how to fix this ?

Comment: Check that, into your xml file do you specify comment line with the space? Or any tag is mismatch.

Comment: I am not sure what xml file to look into?

Comment: check custom extension config file and theme layout files.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179909/46249 Maybe it helps.

Comment: None of the above helped. However I think, but not 100% sure, that I was missing files in /js/* and /lib/* uploaded fresh original files from magento.com, uploaded and it seems the problem was solved.