# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 64: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I'm using magento 1.9.1.0 and getting this error while accessing the site.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 64: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in /home/**/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
```

I used this command to find out the invalid xml `find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} \;` and fix the xml files also. All of the files are showing valid if checking on any validator online. But still getting the issue on site.

Tried to log

```
Mage::log(print_r($xmlString, true));
Mage::log(print_r($this->_elementClass, true));
```

and got this result.
[image]

Can anyone tell me what is the exact issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179909/46249

Answer (score 0):

Though linting by brute force may cover all basis but that isn't really narrowing down the issue.

I'm sure you cleared cache after doing those changes.

With that in mind, try to find exactly when this error is occurring by logging out put before or after line 383:

```
Mage::log(print_r($xmlString, true));
Mage::log(print_r($this->_elementClass, true));
```

Now fix the error from the culprit file, check system log.

NOTE: will update with complete answer after feedback from OP

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried to get invalid files but it is printing a lot of data that i'm unable to figure it out

Comment: Please post a sample of the output

Comment: I updated my post please check

Comment: **1.**  Is there no further output after the initial Warning error?    
**2.**  output doesn't help much :) Try matching up when the Warning occurs (timestamp) with the same timestamp of the output, may help narrow it down.